# Конвертирование коллекции HTML-файлов в PDF-файлы в многопоточной среде

Tags: c#, многопоточность

### ЗАДАЧА

Необходимо большое количество html-файлов (30-40 тыс.) конвертировать в pdf (по отдельности) и сделать это максимально быстро. И для этого идет попытка применить многопоточность. Html-файлы есть одностраничные документ-отчеты с результатами отдельно взятого участника тестирования.

---

### РЕШЕНИЕ. ОДИН ПОТОК

Ниже представлен класс-обработчик, который осуществляет конвертацию в *одном* потоке и клиентский код.

**HtmlProcessor.cs**

```
public class HtmlProcessor
{
    private readonly string _htmlFolder;
    private readonly string _pdfFolder;

    public HtmlProcessor(string htmlFolder)
    {
        _htmlFolder = htmlFolder;

        //Create folder to store pdf-files
        _pdfFolder = Path.Combine(_htmlFolder, "pdfs"); 
        if (!Directory.Exists(_pdfFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_pdfFolder);
        }                
    }

    public void Start()
    {                        
        var htmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(_htmlFolder);
        foreach (var item in htmlFiles)
        {
            ConvertHtmlToPdf(item);             
        }          
    }

    private void ConvertHtmlToPdf(object fullFileName)
    {
        var fullFileNameStr = (string)fullFileName;
        var converter = new HtmlToPdf();

        var pdfDocument = converter.ConvertHtmlString(File.ReadAllText(fullFileNameStr));

        pdfDocument.Save($@"{_pdfFolder}\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullFileNameStr)}.pdf"); 
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var htmlProcessor = new HtmlProcessor("c:\htmlReports");
    htmlProcessor.Start();
}
```

За 1 минуту удалось конвертировать *60* файлов.

---

### РЕШЕНИЕ. МНОГО ПОТОКОВ

Теперь метод `Start()` немного изменен для обработке коллекции файлов в многопоточном режиме.

```
public void Start()
{                        
    var htmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(_htmlFolder);
    foreach (var item in htmlFiles)
    {
        var myThread = new Thread(ConvertHtmlToPdf);
        myThread.Start(item);                
    }          
}
```

За 1 минуту удалось конвертировать *50* файлов.

---

### ВОПРОС

Почему при использовании многопоточности скорость обработки не увеличилась, а наоборот уменьшилась?

И наблюдая за папкой куда сохранялись файлы-pdf, я заметил, что добавление шло строго по 4 файла одновременно. Это наверное потому что у моего процессора 4 потока? Я смог это увидеть в CPU-Z.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина в том, что количество физических потоков процессора ограничено(Вы загружаете процессор на 100 %, переключение контекста и прочий оверхед). У Вас всего 2 физических ядра(с HThreading - 4). Вам нужно использовать ThreadPool и таски, создавать потоки вручную - излишне, они слишком низкоуровневые.  Используйте TaskFactory.

Comment: Спасибо. Я применил `TPL` и получил прирост в производительности на 130%. И теперь как пишет ниже @Alexander Petrov я пытаюсь распараллелить только `узкое место` - этим оказалось `конвертирование в pdf`. Для этого я создал отдельно вопрос http://bit.ly/2qGOj74. Хотел-бы чтобы Вы посмотрели.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала нужно определить узкое место.

В процессе конвертации сперва происходит чтение с диска, потом обработка, потом запись на диск. Так вот если именно обработка занимает основное время, то её распараллеливание может помочь.

Однако, если большая часть времени уходит на операции ввода-вывода, то распараллеливание обработки большого смысла не имеет. [Закон Амдала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

В этом случае может помочь запись на другой *физический* (не *логический*) диск - это тоже своего рода распараллеливание на два устройства ввода-вывода.

---

Метод `Directory.GetFiles` возвращает массив всех найденных файлов. Если у вас их действительно 30-40 тысяч, то формирование этого массива займёт приличное время. Наверняка использование `Directory.EnumerateFiles` будет лучше.

Comment: Спасибо. Узким местом оказалось `конвертирование в pdf`. Я создал новую тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/666006/14935 где пытаюсь правильно распараллелить именно эту задачу. Хочу чтобы Вы взлянули.