# В конвейере «чтение-ОБРАБОТКА-сохранение» распараллелить ОБРАБОТКА

Tags: c#, многопоточность, tpl

В процессе *чтение-обработка-сохранение* было найдено узкое место *обработка* - конвертирование html в pdf - это часть занимает больше всего времени.

Вроде получилось вырвать кусок *обработка-сохранение* в отдельный поток:

```
public class HtmlProcessor
{
    private readonly string _htmlFolder;
    private readonly string _pdfFolder;

    public HtmlProcessor(string htmlFolder)
    {
        _htmlFolder = htmlFolder;

        //Create folder to store pdf-files
        _pdfFolder = Path.Combine(_htmlFolder, "pdfs"); 
        if (!Directory.Exists(_pdfFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_pdfFolder);
        }                
    }

    public void Process()
    {    
        var htmlFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(_htmlFolder);
        foreach (var htmlFileName in htmlFileNames)
        {
            var htmlFileContent = File.ReadAllText(htmlFileName);              

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdf();
                var pdfDocument = htmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(htmlFileContent);

                pdfDocument.Save($@"{_pdfFolder}\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(htmlFileName)}.pdf");
            });
        }            
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var htmlProcessor = new HtmlProcessor("c:\htmlFilesFolder");
    htmlProcessor.Process();
}
```

---

### ВОПРОС

Теперь хочется оторвать *обработка*, чтобы только эта часть выполнялась параллельно. Я не знаю как должна для этого выглядеть логика. Догадываюсь, что, что-то вроде *поток в потоке* будет.

Итого вопрос:  как выглядит многопоточность когда хочется распараллелить задачу из середины некого процесса?

Comment: [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh228603.aspx)?

Comment: @PetSerAl не знал про `TPL Dataflow`. Сейчас читаю/разбираюсь...

Comment: В базисе выглядит как очереди. чтение->ставим в очередь обработки,  из которой выгребается и обрабатывается параллельно-> результат ставим в очередь сохранения. Очередь, например, может быть представлена BlockingCollection. А еще можно всю цепочку как PLINQ описать. Можно Dataflow...в общем вариантов куча

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, попробуйте PLINQ:

```
var htmlFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(_htmlFolder); // EnumerateFiles

htmlFileNames.AsParallel().ForAll(htmlFileName =>
{
    var htmlFileContent = File.ReadAllText(htmlFileName);
    var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdf();
    var pdfDocument = htmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(htmlFileContent);
    pdfDocument.Save($@"{_pdfFolder}\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(htmlFileName)}.pdf");
});
```

TPL сама сделает распараллеливание. Причём количество запускаемых задач будет зависеть от количества ядер в системе.

---

Инициализация потока/задачи, даже если они берутся из пула, дело довольно долгое. В итоге, расходы на неё могут нивелировать всю выгоду от распараллеливания, если обработка каждого файла коротка.

В таком случае, нужно каждую задачу нагрузить обработкой диапазона файлов.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


var htmlFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(_htmlFolder);

Partitioner.Create(0, htmlFileNames.Length).AsParallel().ForAll(range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        string htmlFileName = htmlFileNames[i];
        var htmlFileContent = File.ReadAllText(htmlFileName);
        var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdf();
        var pdfDocument = htmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(htmlFileContent);
        pdfDocument.Save($@"{_pdfFolder}\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(htmlFileName)}.pdf");
    }
});
```

Метод `Partitioner.Create` создаёт диапазоны значений, которые и обрабатываются в каждой задаче.

Замечу, что `Directory.EnumerateFiles` в данном случае неприменим: нужно изначально знать размер коллекции.

---

Ещё примечание. Я не знаю, что за класс `HtmlToPdf`. Если его создание ресурсоёмко и метод `ConvertHtmlString` можно вызывать многократно, то есть смысл вынести его за цикл.

```
Partitioner.Create(0, htmlFileNames.Length).AsParallel().ForAll(range =>
{
    var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdf();
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        string htmlFileName = htmlFileNames[i];
        var htmlFileContent = File.ReadAllText(htmlFileName);

        var pdfDocument = htmlToPdf.ConvertHtmlString(htmlFileContent);
        pdfDocument.Save($@"{_pdfFolder}\{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(htmlFileName)}.pdf");
    }
});
```